# Compare String time to Local Server Time

Tags: date, java-8, java-time, datetime-parsing, datetime-conversion

Have a string object with a specific format of date.
Need to check if that dateStr is after the current time on local machine.
Having trouble with conversions and `LocalDateTime`

```
String dateStr = "Oct 27 2017 02:29:00 GMT+0000";
public static final String DATE_FORMAT = "MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zzzZ";
```

I know something is fishy in the below code with the usage of `LocalDateTime`

```
public static boolean isFutureDate(String dateStr){
      DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_FORMAT);
      LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateStr, formatter);
      return(dateTime.isAfter(LocalDateTime.now()));
}
```

Trouble is with timezones and date conversions. 
Please help find the right way of checking if a dateStr is after the current local date this in Java 8?

Comment: plz include the content of the constant DATE_FORMAT...

Comment: Added DATE_FORMAT

Comment: Whats your definition of fishy here? Any errors that you could see?

Comment: No, the response returned is not expected. And I know for a fact that LocalDateTime does not consider timezones.

Comment: @AshokFelix The code shared above returns `false` for me which I find appropriate given the time mentioned in the string is actually before my current local date time.

Comment: And it returns false even when it's after the time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When parsing to a `LocalDateTime`, you're ignoring the offset (`+0000`), and I'm not sure if that's what you really want.

In this case, the `+0000` offset means the date/time is October 27<sup>th</sup> 2017 at 02:29 AM in **UTC**. When you parse to a `LocalDateTime`, you're ignoring the offset (so it represents only "October 27<sup>th</sup> 2017 at 02:29 AM", not attached to any timezone) and comparing to your local date/time (or the current date/time in the JVM's default timezone).

If you want to make a comparison that also considers the offset, you can parse it to `OffsetDateTime` and convert to `Instant` to compare it with the actual UTC instant, regardless of the timezone.

Also, the month name is in English (I'm assuming it's English, but you can change this accordingly), so you must a `java.util.Locale` in the formatter (if you don't set a locale, it'll use the JVM default, and it's not guaranteed to always be English):

```
// parse to OffsetDateTime (use the same formatter)
String dateStr = "Oct 27 2017 02:29:00 GMT+0000";
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zzzZ", Locale.US);
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateStr, fmt);
// compare Instant's
System.out.println(odt.toInstant().isAfter(Instant.now()));
```

Although it works for you now, keep in mind that the default locale can be changed without notice, even at runtime. If your input has locale-sensitive date (such as month names), it's better to specify it as above.

Comment: On the note of parsing the date, the format is [parsed appropriately](https://ideone.com/vlu0Og).

Comment: The first code block does not give me expected with the current GMT time and my local time. I'm trying your second method. But the parser works as expected :)

Comment: @AshokFelix The first code block just gets the date and time and ignores the offset - it doesn't make any conversions

Comment: @nullpointer Indeed, the format `zzzZ` works, I've made a typo when testing and thought it didn't. I've removed that note from the answer, thanks!

Comment: @AshokFelix The parser works because your JVM's default locale is probably English (or any other that recognizes "Oct" as month name), but it's not guaranteed to work in all configurations (my JVM is set to Portuguese and it fails if I don't set a specific locale) - I've added a note in the answer about it

Comment: @Hugo I tested it with a sample time of current gmt - 5 mins and gmt + 5 mins and both return false with both the samples above :(

Comment: @AshokFelix Could you please edit your question and add examples of inputs and outputs that fail?

Comment: @Hugo - Some more trials worked. I'm just testing with the current GMT time +/- a few minutes as input. Thank you.

Comment: @AshokFelix The input corresponds to `2017-10-27T02:29Z` (2:29 AM in UTC), which corresponds to an instant that happened more than 13 hours ago. So adding a few minutes will still be in the past. Anyway, I'm glad it worked!

Comment: @hugo Considered that. I changed the constant string dateStr  to before current UTC and after current UTC. Got it

Answer (score 4):

## `Local…` types have no time zone

You are using the wrong type for your data.

The `Local…` types including `LocalDateTime` purposely have no concept of time zone or offset-from UTC. As such they *not* represent a moment on the time line, only rough idea of a range of possible moments. Use `LocalDateTime` only when the time zone is unknown or irrelevant; never use it for an actual moment in history.

Use `OffsetDateDate` for values with an offset-from-UTC, a number of hours and minutes.

Use `ZonedDateTime` for values with an assigned time zone. A time zone such as `Asia/Kolkata` or `America/Montreal` is a particular region’s history of past, present, and future changes to its offset-from-UTC. Anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) mean a change to the offset.

If you know all your inputs are in GMT/UTC, use `OffsetDateTime`. If the inputs may use time zones, parse as `ZonedDateTime` objects.

This input data format is terrible. If you have any control, use standard ISO 8601 formats instead when exchanging date-time values as text.

All this has been covered many times already on Stack Exchange. Please search more thoroughly before posting. And search Stack Overflow to learn more. I kept my Answer here brief, as this is a duplicate.